# Is there a way to change the background of a single cell in ultragrid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, infragistics

I've looked on the offical infragistics site and in multiple forums but either it changes the backcolor of the whole row or of the column.
Here some pseudocode of what i want to achieve:

```
If cellValue != 0 or  cellValue Isnot nothing

    change background color of cellValue to yellow
```

Do you have an idea how to do that?
I appreciate any help, prefered in vb.net or c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the solution with the help of Marco. My goal was to change the cell Color in specific columns if their value isn't 0. You need to do this in the InitalizeRow Event btw. Here's what I did:

```
For Each column As UltraGridColumn In ugResult.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns
                If column.ToString = "K_Art" Or column.ToString = "UANR" Or column.ToString = "Ueberbegriff" Or column.ToString = "Benennung" Or column.ToString = "Anzahl" Or column.ToString = "Einheit" Or column.ToString = "Einzelkosten" Or column.ToString = "Sumcode" Or column.ToString = "Status" Then
                    Exit For
                Else
                    For Each r As UltraGridRow In ugResult.Rows
                        If r.Cells(column.Index).Value <> 0 Then
                            r.Cells(column.Index).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                        End If

                    Next
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If e.Row.Cells("CELL_NAME").Text <> 0 Then
        e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red   'change row's color
        e.Row.Cells("CELL_NAME").Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red    'change cell's color
End If
```

This Code works on InitializeRows Event.
The code you write in this event is executed on all lines of the grid.

Comment: I get the following Error [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30518?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC30518).

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: `Select Case result.Status
            Case Status.Modified
                Dim cell As UltraGridCell = Me.ugResult.Rows(1).Cells(1)
                e.Row.Cells(cell).Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        End Select`

Comment: Code i posted, you have to put inside "InitializeRow Event". Like this:                                       Private Sub ugResult_InitializeRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeRowEventArgs) Handles ugResult.InitializeRow  [then post codice i posted].  Try this.

Comment: What is "CELL_NAME" supposed to do? I don't have the specific cell names. I have to iterate through the grid and if in the column "Price" for example the cell value is not 0 and not nothing, then the cell should be colored.

Comment: CELL_NAME is the name of the cell. So you have to write "Price".  IF you don't have name you can use the index [ .Cells(1) ] for example.